# How to add trash can to Plank

Tags: trash, dock, plank

I have been trying to add the trash can to Plank, but I cannot figure out how to do it (Ubuntu 15.10). I see instructions on how to do it for Elementary OS, but I have no knowledge of Elementary OS so I don't know how to convert the code to work for Ubuntu, if it is even possible.

Does anyone know how to get the trash can on Plank?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done but as far as I can see it does not have the full functionality of the actual 'Trash'. Create a new .dockitem with the following command:

```
touch $HOME/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/trash.dockitem
```

and then add the following to this file:

```
[PlankDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=trash://
```

Attached is a screenshot showing the Trash in place in the dock:

[image]

Hopefully this will be enough for you? Unfortunately functionality that I see missing here is:

1. Icon does not change whether Trash is full or empty
2. No right click functionality to 'Empty' the Trash

Comment: This seems to be a solution for the issues you list in this answer, I have not tried it though https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/25c8g9/trash_can_for_plank_great_for_elementary_os/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4 with Plank version 0.11.3, and it already has this feature.

1. Right click **Plank** on the desktop
2. Choose **preferences**
3. Click **Docklets** then double click **Trash**

[image: Screenshot of plank preferences]

[image: Screenshot of the final effect in plank]