# No plank configuration file

Tags: settings, customization, plank

I want to manually customize my plank dock but when I go to the plank directory, looking for the settings file, I only find the launchers directory, and not what I'm looking for.

I already searched on some forums, but everybody recommend to use `docky` or another dock which is not available for ubuntu 19.04, the version I'm currently using.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Comment: What is exactly the context of the question? In what way would you like to edit settings? From cli?

Comment: I want to manually customize the plank configuration file to change the color of the little circle under the applicaation icon that is showed when a window is open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plank makes use of [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/) and [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) to manage it's configuration. The configuration is stored together with the configuration of other applications which use GSettings in a single file. You will find this file in `~/.config/dconf/`, in my system it's `~/.config/dconf/user`. This is not a text file, you can't edit it in a text editor.

Use Plank's preferences window to edit your docks, to open the preferences window hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the right mouse button while the cursor is over the dock, in the context menu choose `Preferences`.

To change the color of the little circle under the application icon that is shown when a window is open, you will have to either choose a different theme or edit the theme you are currently using. Plank themes are located in `/usr/share/plank/themes/` or `~/.local/share/plank/themes/`.

You can also install additional themes, take a look at

- https://github.com/alma4rebi/Plank-Themes-1
- https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/273/

Comment: [Plank also has configuration stuff in `$HOME/.config/plank/dock...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/750948/479118`)

Answer (score 0):

dconf-editor will give you the ability to edit the plank settings if it is stubbornly auto-hiding (try changing the 'auto' setting under 'hide-mode' in /net/launchpad/plank/docks/dock1 to 'Intellihide'), then you can access the more friendly plank menu with Ctrl-rClick as others have mentioned. I have had issues in MATE with running plank on the bottom,  widgets in the panel conflict/preempt plank under several themes -- I use {blush} Redmond as my 'daily driver', and plank sometimes misbehaves unless I locate it Left or Right with auto-hide set to "Intellihide".